# How to send EOF to Python sys.stdin from commandline? CTRL-D doesn't work

Tags: python, unix, command-line, buffer

I am writing to my Python process from the commandline on unix. I want to send EOF (or somehow flush the stdin buffer, so Python can read my input.)

If I hit CTRL-C, I get a KeyboardError.

If I hit CTRL-D, the program just stops.

How do I flush the stdin buffer?

Comment: The way most terminals work, as soon as you hit Enter, your input gets sent to Python.

Comment: If you want to change how that works, Python has to change terminal settings, which is black magic... see the `termios` module perhaps? http://docs.python.org/library/termios.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use 'for l in sys.stdin', it is buffered.

You can use:

```
  while 1:
     l = sys.stdin.readline()
```

Comment: It's buffered anyway. There's no difference between the two.

Comment: Actually, the above worked for me.

I think I read on the mailing list that 'for l in sys.stdin' has an extra internal buffer, whereas sys.stdin.readline() does not.

Comment: @JasonOrendorff: actually there is a difference on Python 2 due to [read-ahead buffer bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue3907). You could use `for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):` to workaround it. Try to run `cat | python2 -u -c"<use sys.stdin or sys.stdin.readline() here>"` and type some input. `readline()` variant leads to the lines being available immediately.

Answer (score 14):

Control-D should NOT make your program "just stop" -- it should close standard input, and if your program deals with that properly, it may perfectly well continue if it needs to!

For example, given the following `st.py`:

```
import sys

def main():
  inwas = []
  for line in sys.stdin:
    inwas.append(line)
  print "%d lines" % len(inwas),
  print "initials:", ''.join(x[0] for x in inwas)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

we could see something like

```
$ python st.py
nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita
mi ritrovai per una selva oscura
che la diritta via era smarrita
3 lines initials: nmc
$
```

if the control-D is hit right after the enter on the third line -- the program realizes that standard input is done, and performs the needed post-processing, all neat and proper.

If your program prematurely exits on control-D, it must be badly coded -- what about editing you question to add the smallest "misbehaving" program you can conceive of, so we can show you exactly HOW you're going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what's happening.  You are hitting `ctrl-D` without hitting `enter`.  If you want to send a line to the program, just hit enter.  If you hit `ctrl-D` without hitting `enter`, you can hit `ctrl-D` again and your program should see the line then.  In this case (two `ctrl-D`s in succession), your program will not see a newline at the end of the line.

For example, let's say I have a Python script `a.py`:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write('%s' % line)
```

And I execute it:

```
$ python a.py
```

And then enter the following:

```
line 1
line 2<ctrl-D><ctrl-D>
```

the program will print:

```
line 1
line 2$
```

`$` is the shell-prompt.  Here's a full session with the above input:

$ python a.py
line 1
line 2 **line1** 
**line 2**$

(**Bold** show the program's output.  Roman-case is for showing what I typed, sans the two `ctrl-D`s)

If this is not what's happening, you need to tell us more about what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    # You might be inside the while-loop
    foo = raw_input('Spam: ') # Or whatever...
except EOFError:
    print 'And now for something completely different.'
    sys.exit()
```